# Magical trigonometric inequality (feat. number theory)

Tags: number-theory, inequality, trigonometry, prime-numbers

A couple of days ago I found an [interesting problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3168453) on the Art of Problem Solving website. It says:

> For odd and coprime positive integers $p$ and $q$, the following inequality holds
> $$ \sum_{m=1}^{p} \sum_{n=1}^{q} \frac{2}{\cos(\frac{2m\pi}{p})+\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{q})} \le pq(|p-q|+1). $$

The magical thing is that the equality holds for some non-trivial examples, such as $(p,q)=(23,31), (29,31)$ (I have checked via WolframAlpha), while for some other $(p,q)$ the bound is rather loose. This suggests that crude boundings cannot apply, and there might be an identity behind it. The strange equality case also hints at the relation to prime numbers.

Pairing $m \leftrightarrow p-m$ and $n \leftrightarrow q-n$ seems plausible, but appears to be of little use. I tried directly compute $\sum_{n=1}^{q} \frac{2}{\cos(\frac{2m\pi}{p})+\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{q})}$ for a fixed $m$, but I find it hard to deal with. Also, the cosine terms may related to eigenvalues of circulant matrices, but I don't know how to interpret $\cos(\frac{2m\pi}{p})+\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{q})$.

Any ideas or comments are welcome.

**Edit:** I numerically compute the values for all odd numbers $p \le q<50$ (without requiring $\gcd(p,q)=1$). Exclude trivial cases $p=q$ or $p=1$, other equality cases are as follows:
$$ \color{red}{(3,7)},(5,7),\color{red}{(5,11)},\color{red}{(7,15)},(9,11),(9,13),\color{red}{(9,19)},(11,15),\color{red}{(11,23)},(13,15),(13,19),\color{red}{(13,27)},\color{red}{(15,31)},(17,19),(17,21),(17,23),(17,25),\color{red}{(17,35)},(19,23),\color{red}{(19,39)},(21,23),(21,31),\color{red}{(21,43)},(23,31),\color{red}{(23,47)},(25,27),(25,29),(25,31),(25,37),(27,31),(29,31),(29,35),(29,39),(29,43),(33,35),(33,37),(33,41),(33,49),(35,39),(35,47),(37,39),(37,43),(39,47),(41,43),(41,45),(41,47),(43,47),(45,47). $$
It appears that $q \le 2p+1$ should hold for equality to occur, and $q=2p+1$ indeed gives equality. But I don't find other structures.

Comment: Can you find all the equality cases?

Comment: I add the equality cases when $p \le q<50$.

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea since the number of equality cases is not small.